# HDD spins up/down in a strange way during Windows 8 shutdown

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, ahci

In my PC I have one SSD and one HDD. In the SSD I have installed Windows 8, while the HHD is for personal data storage. Until yesterday the SSD was in AHCI mode and the HDD in IDE mode.

The problem is that today I switch (from BIOS) also the HHD in AHCI mode (basically because this HDD runs also a linux partition). The HDD still works fine in Windows 8, but when I shutdown my system:

- The HDD spins down, then
- the HDD spins up again!
- finally the HDD spins down and Win 8 shutdowns.

When the HDD was in IDE mode there wasn't this problem. How can I fix it?

This is my hardware configuration:

- **MOBO**: Asus M4A785TD-M EVO
- **SSD**: OCZ Agility 3 60GB
- **HDD**: Samsung HD103JS 1TB
- **OS**: Windows 8 Professional 64 bit + Chakra Linux 64 bit

UPDATE: I don't know if it is related, but today my HDD spins down and WHEN I try to access it through windows files manager, Windows get a BSOD with INTERNAL_POWER_ERROR...